# How to make a nodeJS into an executable that doesn't show the prompt

Tags: node.js, hide, command-prompt, pkgbuild

I made a code in node.JS and compiled it and turned it into an executable, but, when I open the executable, it opens the command prompt, and in my case, it cannot open the prompt.

There is some way to hide the prompt for my executable from node js?

My attempt:

```
pkg myfile.js --output executavel.exe -quiet
```

I've tried to use visual basic too, but it doesn't compile the exe in one file without prompt.